# SQL group date as one revision history/batch?

Tags: sql-server

This is my starting table

```
+--------+---------+-------+------------+<br>
|  make  |  model  | Class |    Date    |<br>
+--------+---------+-------+------------+<br>
| honda  | accord  |     1 | 2015070169 |<br>
| honda  | civic   |     2 | 2015070169 |<br>
| honda  | fit     |     3 | 2015070169 |<br>
| toyota | camry   |     1 | 2015080954 |<br>
| BMW    | 7Series |     1 | 2015080959 |<br>
| BMW    | 5series |     2 | 2015080959 |<br>
| BMW    | 3Series |     3 | 2015080959 |<br>
+--------+---------+-------+------------+<br>
```

Based on the table above the date is already doing a good job grouping it. but it would be easier on the eye if those date are ordered in batch like bellow

```
+--------+---------+-------+------------+---------+<br>
|  make  |  model  | Class |    Date    | History |<br>
+--------+---------+-------+------------+---------+<br>
| honda  | accord  |     1 | 2015070169 |       1 |<br>
| honda  | civic   |     2 | 2015070169 |       1 |<br>
| honda  | fit     |     3 | 2015070169 |       1 |<br>
| toyota | camry   |     1 | 2015080954 |       2 |<br>
| BMW    | 7Series |     1 | 2015080959 |       3 |<br>
| BMW    | 5series |     2 | 2015080959 |       3 |<br>
| BMW    | 3Series |     3 | 2015080959 |       3 |<br>
+--------+---------+-------+------------+---------+<br>
```

the closest I get to my goal is using this SQL query

```
select make, model, class, date, 
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by class order by date) AS HISTORY
from table1
order by date
```

this is the result from above query

```
+--------+---------+-------+------------+---------+<br>
|  make  |  model  | Class |    Date    | History |<br>
+--------+---------+-------+------------+---------+<br>
| honda  | accord  |     1 | 2015070169 |       1 |<br>
| honda  | civic   |     2 | 2015070169 |       1 |<br>
| honda  | fit     |     3 | 2015070169 |       1 |<br>
| toyota | camry   |     1 | 2015080954 |       2 |<br>
| BMW    | 7Series |     1 | 2015080959 |       3 |<br>
| BMW    | 5series |     2 | 2015080959 |       2 |<br>
| BMW    | 3Series |     3 | 2015080959 |       2 |<br>
+--------+---------+-------+------------+---------+<br>
<br>
```

but it is still not what I want . because I partition by class thus class 1 has history 1,2 and 3 , while the other class  is only 1 and 2.

what would be a better method to achieve this.

Comment: Are you trying to get the order right or the History number right?

Comment: correct, the second table is my goal. but I cannot get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DENSE_RANK() over (order by date) to give them numbers based on date.

```
select make, model, class, date
,DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by [date] ASC) AS HISTORY
from table1
order by date
```

**ROW_NUMBER()** - Assigns a unique number to each row. The number is unique within the partition.

**RANK()** - Assigns a number to each row, but if the values are the same they get the same number. The numbers are separated by how many have that rank. For example: 1,1,3,3

**DENSE_RANK()** - Same as rank but the numbers are closer together. For example: 1,1,2,2

Comment: if you notice, there are three different date in my table, 2015070169, 2015080954,2015080959. and  I just need an extra column to tell me that the first date is "group 1", the second date is "group 2", and the third date is "group 3"

Comment: See my edit, I think this might be more what you want.

Comment: I tried that. it actually gets me 1,2,3,1,1,2,3 .. let me build a sql fiddle

Comment: OK, should be the DENSE_RANK function instead. I'll add some more description of why but my answer is up now.